# Responsive nav bar menu not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with a  responsive nav bar menu,  when I open it from a mobile browser everything works fine but when I use my finger and slide to the left the overflow content shows, I have tried using `overflow:hidden` and `overflow-x:hidden` on both my body tag and my div wrapper tag, I have played with different display positions, I have seen a lot of possible solutions to similar questions here, and I've tried them all, yet I have not been able to find a solution, does anyone have any idea on this issue?

Here is a link to my web page with the nav bar:
https://unruffled-wright-0b9f34.netlify.app

And here is my html, css and  javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@500;600&family=Lobster&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;1,200&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>El Foraneo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">

      <h1>EL Foraneo </h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">item1 </a></>
      <li><a href="#">item2 </a></>
      <li><a href="#">item3 </a></>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #E08876;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
  
}
.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-links a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body{
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh; 
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #E08876;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease in;
    
  
     
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}
.nav-active {

  transform: translateX(0%);
  

}
@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from{
       opacity: 0;
       transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to{
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
.toggle .line1{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
.toggle .line2{
  opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3{
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```
//function declaration

const navSlide = () => {
  //variables
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

  //Event Listener
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //links with animation
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {


      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      }
      else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.2}s`;
      }


    });

    //Burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

  });
```

Comment: Hey, welcome. Just so you know, it is really hard for us to assist if you do not provide any code to show the issue. Can you please update your question to include this? Edit, I can see some css in an image, please put that in as code, and also include the html :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can change nav-links position from absolute to fixed. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `overflow:hide` style for body so remove it, and just apply the style i give below:

in your `style.css` in media query add or append below rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .nav-links {
    // all your other styles
    display: none; // add this new line 
  }
 
  // add below new rule for nav-active class.
  .nav-active {
     display: flex;
  }
}
```

Try it, it will work, if not then tell me the issues, peace.

Comment: @EdChávezOrtiz if it worked then please accept the answer, if you don't know then just click on right sign before my answer. or look at the guide [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/403397)